# CodeIgniter internal redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I want to handle all requests with one controller and I have a route

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'links/index/$1';
```

and table in my database(screenshot below)

[image]

So when URL is mydomain.com/first-article I am selecting from database controller, action, and table-id and I want to redirect to articles controller, article action and pass table_id.
How can I do it?

Also I need to keep URL

> mydomain.com/first-article

Then I redirecting with redirect() I am getting error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, because of $route['(:any)'] = 'links/index/$1';
```

Comment: You should handle this redirect with an htaccess file

Comment: Can You give small example how it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

I have to be honest, I don't mess with routes. Instead, I grabbed the part of the url with the uri->segment

Just an idea for you

```
//example
//linksid
    $links_id = intval($this->uri->segment(3, 0));
```

so http://www.mydomain.com/mycontroller/go/1 would grab 1 and then I can redirect from there...

Answer (score 1):

The infinite redirection happens because of your routes configuration. Your routes rule is

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'links/index/$1';
```

Which means what ever comes after domain name execute the link controllers index action. For example lets say the URl is   `http://www.mydomain.com/articles/article`, CI would execute the links controller index function with `articles` as argument. And in links controller you fetch the db and redirect to another controller.But due to routes configuration the link controller will be executed again. So there becomes a redirection loop.

if you need articles controller to be executed you have to add another rule above it like below:

```
 $route['articles/article/(:any)'] = 'articles/article/$1';
```

I suggest first you make a good thought on your url pattern and then write the routes.

Comment: But I want to have URL structure like this: domain.com/my-article or domain.com/my-products or domain.com/user-name. The structure is same, but controllers and acions is different.

Comment: if you decide on a url suffix or prefix, for example my-article, say all articles will have the suffix `-article` then you can write `$routes['(:any)-article'] = 'articles/article/$1'`. i hope you got my point

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using CodeIgniter Modular Extensions - HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc. Now I can run any module in any contorller.